# How to make an AI respond to its name being called in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I was experimenting with virtual assistance and was wondering how to make it respond to its name being called. Currently I have a button that activates `listen()` for the program to start listening for commands but how do i activate `listen()` by calling the AI's name? Thanks in advance.

Code for button

```
<center>
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored" onclick="listen()">
      <i class="material-icons">mic</i>
    </button>
    <hr>
    <span id="stuff">test</span>
</center>
```

Code for `listen()`

```
function listen() {
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.onresult = function(event) { 
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            $("#stuff").text(event.results[0][0].transcript)
        }
    }
}
```